# Append items list in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, for-loop

I've the following two array that I want to append in div id using `Jquery`

```
["Item-1:SOMETHING1", "Item-2:SOMETHING2", "Item-1:SOMETHING3"]
["Code-1:123", "Code-2:456", "Code-1:789"]
```

Arrays have the information of items to be print in their respective div's.
I'm facing problems of extracting items in my arrays.
The first arrat have `Item-1` and `Item-1` that should be append in `ITEMDIV-1`
with their codes that are Code-1 and Code-2
Similarly,
The Item-1 after the Item-2 and the Code-1 after the Code-2 should be append in `ITEMDIV-2` and so on.
How can I append them using for loop and .append() function of jquery.

My Code:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    if($("#ITEMDIV"+i).length != 0) {
    // append here
    }
}
```

**Desired Output:**

```
First Iteration:

Item-1:SOMETHING1
Item-2:SOMETHING2
Code-1:123
Code-2:456


Second Iteration:

Item-1:SOMETHING3
Code-1:789
```

Comment: your question is very unclear, can you put an example of the expected result in html?

Comment: Very unclear and makes no sense to me

Comment: @Aleuck expected result is shown in following answer.

Comment: @Harko I want to list items in respective div's. I had these arrays. I want to append these to them simply.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
var items = ["Item-1:SOMETHING1", "Item-2:SOMETHING2", "Item-1:SOMETHING3"];
var codes = ["Code-1:123", "Code-2:456", "Code-1:789"];

var arr = items.concat(codes);

$.each(arr, function(key, val) {
  $("div[id^=ITEMDIV]").each(function(i, el) {
    if (new RegExp(el.id.replace(/ITEMDIV/, "")).test(val)) {
      $(el).append(val + "<br />")
    };
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<div id="ITEMDIV-1"></div>
<br />
<div id="ITEMDIV-2"></div>
```

Comment: How about if I have more than 2 items div's ? how can it to be dynamic?

Comment: Just I want to list item1 then Item2 in same list. Then the next Item1. Let me update my question

Comment: You are very much right, but a little misunderstanding. Please check the updated querstion. By the way, thanks in advance.

Comment: @developer _"Desired Output"_ at updated Question appear different than description at original Question ? , _"The first arrat have Item-1 and Item-1 that should be append in ITEMDIV-1 with their codes that are Code-1 and Code-2 Similarly, The Item-1 after the Item-2 and the Code-1 after the Code-2 should be append in ITEMDIV-2 and so on."_ ?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, I want to say on each iteration of items from 1 to n, each should  be append in their resective div along with their codes.

Answer (score 0):

It don't look like you understand the arrays properly and it's not really clear what you are trying to do.

If your trying to match ITEMDIV-1 then append, this will never happen as the 1st item your searching for is ITEMDIV0, then ITEMDIV1, etc

```
var items = ["Item-1:SOMETHING1", "Item-2:SOMETHING2", "Item-1:SOMETHING3"];
var codes = ["Code-1:123", "Code-2:456", "Code-1:789"];

for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
if($("#ITEMDIV-"+i).length != 0) {
// append here
}
}
```

This will now match ITEMDIV-0, ITEMDIV-1, ITEMDIV-2 etc if they exist.

edit: If needed a init of 1 then start the for loop at 1 and use and array index

```
var arrayIndex;
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
if($("#ITEMDIV-"+i).length != 0) {
arrayIndex=i-1;
// append here
}
}
```

Comment: Ohhh, it should be init by one. and yes I'm a bit confused in arrays in for loops.

Comment: Your update makes less sense. There is only 1 loop, 1 shot so even if it did work like you expected it would would only ever see the last Iteration.